# Создание сложного заголовка в C# WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Необходимо создать таблицу, которая будет иметь следующую шапку, желательно использовать MVVM [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сами что то пробовали? Что гугл говорит о вашей задаче?

Comment: очень много на windows forms примеров, на wpf не нашел, вот и спрашиваю

Comment: ну вот что я нагуглил за 10 секунд: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638239/wpf-datagrid-column-heading-span-more-than-once-column), [два](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366/wpf-multicolumn-super-header?forum=wpf), надеюсь, поможет

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: на здоровье :-)